# Есть задание(картинку приложил), код написал, что не так? Необходимо использовать декораторы. Язык Python

Tags: python, декоратор

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```py
def function(foo):
    print(foo)
```

```py
login = input()
balance = 12345
def decorator(func):
    def wrap(*args,**kwargs):
        value = func(*args,**kwargs)
        if value == 'admin':
            return balance
        elif  value != 'admin':
            return 'доступ запрещён'
        return value
    return wrap
    
@decorator
def end(login):
    return login
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы сделали вообще не то. У вас нет функции из пункта 2, соответсвенно и задекорировать вы её не смогли.

```
balance = 2651418

def decorator(func):
    def wrap(login):
        if login=='admin':
            return func(login)
        else:
            return 'доступ запрещён'
    return wrap

@decorator
def my_sum(login):
    return balance

login = input()
print(my_sum(login))
```

Comment: Точно, благодарю Вас за помощь, долго пытался найти в чём проблема.